# How to assign an integer value to each combobox element - c#

Tags: c#

I am making a program that calculates energy usage. I have a combobox of household appliances. When a appliance is selected I want a power rating to be assigned to a variable to then calculate the total energy usage. How do I go about it? Should I double click the combobox and write some appropriate code in the method?

This is a windows form application. All I have done is made a combobox from the toolbox using the design view. I then populated the combobox by clicking Properties>Items. The comboxbox contains one drop down that contains hours (00, 01, 02, 03 etc) and another contains minutes (00, 15, 30, 45). I want to get the values from the combobox and do calculations with them.

Comment: Hi Michael, i see you are new here, welcome! Firstly, your answer is very vague, we need further information and detail, for instances is this winforms or asp.net? secondly can you provide the relevant code that you are working with and your attempts at trying to solve it, for instances the variables and the combobox. Then we can give you a more defined answer :)

Comment: _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Comment: How are you populating the combobox, is it databound to a dataset? How all that information in addition to the advise of the others and we might be able to help you

Comment: Apologies for the poor wording. I've edited my question trying to give more detail

Answer (score 2):

So i tried to make what you asked for

Here i have my forms load event im just setting the datasource of the hours and minutes comboboxes

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var hours = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
        var mins = new int[] { 0, 15, 45};
        hoursComboBox.DataSource = hours;
        minsComboBox.DataSource = mins;
}
```

Create your powerCalculationMethod

```
private int CalculatePower(int hours,int mins)
    {
        //do calculation
        int calc = 0;
        return calc;
    }
```

Then maybe after selecting the values in the comboboxes you could have a button click and on its click event Convert the values of the comboboxes to integers because thats the parameters the method expects and do your calculation

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //set label's text to the calculated power
        //convert the values of the comboboxes to integers so that you could do calculations with them
        //and because the calculatepower method is expecting ints
        //tostring at end to set labels text to a string
        label1.Text = CalculatePower(Convert.ToInt32(this.hoursComboBox.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt32(this.minsComboBox.SelectedValue)).ToString();
    }
```

Maybe this gives you an idea of how you can accomplish what you are trying to do

Comment: I think that your CalculationMethod should returned hours + (mins / 60);

Comment: I totally agree, but i left the calculation logic to him because his question was more how to get the values from his comboboxes

Answer (score 0):

I think the hardest part is to convert the number of minutes from a 60-based number into a 10-based number
here is a global solution:

```
Dictionary<string, double> dictionaryValues = new Dictionary<string, double>();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  comboBoxApplicances.Items.Add("Air conditioning");
  comboBoxApplicances.Items.Add("Attic fan");
  comboBoxApplicances.Items.Add("Ceiling fan");
  comboBoxApplicances.Items.Add("Dishwasher");
  comboBoxApplicances.SelectedIndex = 0;

  dictionaryValues.Add("Air conditioning", 0);
  dictionaryValues.Add("Attic fan", 0);
  dictionaryValues.Add("Ceiling fan", 0);
  dictionaryValues.Add("Dishwasher", 0);

  for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
  {
    comboBoxHours.Items.Add(i < 10 ? "0" + i : i.ToString()); // add 0 for i < 10
  }

  comboBoxHours.SelectedIndex = 0;
  comboBoxMinutes.Items.Add("00");
  comboBoxMinutes.Items.Add("15");
  comboBoxMinutes.Items.Add("30");
  comboBoxMinutes.Items.Add("45");
  comboBoxMinutes.SelectedIndex = 0;
}

private void buttonCompute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // adding value to the selected appliance
  dictionaryValues[comboBoxApplicances.SelectedItem.ToString()] +=
    GetHoursMinutes(comboBoxHours.SelectedItem.ToString(),
    comboBoxMinutes.SelectedItem.ToString());
  labelCurrentApplicance.Text = dictionaryValues[comboBoxApplicances.SelectedItem.ToString()].ToString();
}

private double GetHoursMinutes(string hours, string minutes)
{
  double result = 0;
  double minutesB60 = double.Parse(minutes);
  double minutesB10 = (minutesB60 / 60);
  result = double.Parse(hours) + minutesB10;
  return result;
}
```